# Python: PSQL: Generate list from query

Tags: python, sql, list, psql

I am trying to retrieve some data from a table and output it as a list. The problem is that the resulting list is not in the correct form.

This is my table:
[image]

My code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT tegebruikentags FROM tagstegebruiken WHERE wel_niet_lezen = True")
taglist = cur.fetchall()
print (taglist)
```

The output:

> [('Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT0',), ('Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT4',),
>   ('Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT8',)]

The desired output:

> ['Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT0', 'Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT4',
>   'Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT8']

How should I edit the code in order to get the list as I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using `psycopg2` ?

Comment: At the database side there are also the group aggregation functions: string_agg() , json_agg() etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this automatically with the query, but this is a solution.

```
li = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
print li
'['Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT0', 'Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT4', 'Bakkerij.Device1.DB100INT8']'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using psycopg2 , [`cursor.fetchall`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall) returns a list of tuples, even if there is only a single column in it.

You can convert that list of tuples to a list using -

```
taglist = [i for item in taglist for i in item]
```